# How often and in what manner can one use warm water with salt for oral health?

Tags: dentistry, oral-health, teeth-sensitivity

I have heard about the benefits of swishing with warm salt water. I have hard that it promotes oral health and keeps many oral diseases at bay.

I read a lot about it on the web but all the posts are different from one another in one or the other way. I'm confused after reading them.

So I was wondering if someone could elaborate on it with authenticity.

Here is the question I have :

**How will it benefit oral health?**

Link: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-benefits-of-rinsing-my-gums-with-salt-water

Comment: Would you kindly add into your question a source of two from where you have read  that swishing with warm salt water helps?

Comment: @Jan As per your request I've added a link where many dentists have came forward and answered.

Answer (score 3):

Swishing with warm salt water may not help to prevent mouth disease in otherwise health individuals.

> Salt water rinse can be used as adjunct to routine mechanical plaque
>   control for prevention of oral diseases.
>
> The study participants would have experienced some improvement not
>   specifically associated with the therapeutic properties of the test
>   agent, but rather related to behavioral change known as [Hawthorne
>   effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawthorne_effect). *([jisppd.com](http://www.jisppd.com/article.asp?issn=0970-4388;year=2017;volume=35;issue=4;spage=319;epage=326;aulast=Aravinth))*

Swishing with warm salt water may help to prevent or cure mouth wounds in some conditions:

**1) After tooth extraction**

> The instruction to use warm saline mouth rinse is beneficial in the
>   prevention of alveolar osteitis after dental extractions. There is no
>   significant difference in the efficacy of the twice-daily warm saline
>   mouth rinse regimen compared to the six times daily regimen. *([Evidence-Based Dental Practice, 2015](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25909940))*

**2) After surgery in the mouth,** swishing warm salt water may help prevent infections:

> Chlorhexidine, warm salt water and warm tap water averagely produced
>   the same number of colony forming units of bacteria, which shows that
>   the three different mouth washes are equally effective as
>   post-operative mouth rinses after oral surgery. *([J Maxillofac Oral Surg., 2015](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4444729/))*

**3) After chemotherapy**

> Rinsing with a mixture of saltwater and 3% hydrogen peroxide. (The
>   mixture should have 2 or 3 times the amount of saltwater than hydrogen
>   peroxide.) To make the saltwater mixture, put 1/4 teaspoon of salt in
>   1 cup of water. This helps clean wounds in the mouth. *([PDQ Cancer
>   Information Summaries, 2019](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK65725/))*